# Turn of webcam after snapshot

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I use this code in order to GetUserMedia() and take a snapshot. I would like the camera to turn off after the snap-shot is taken, any tips on how to accomplish this?

```
$("#btnSaves").click(function () {

    var video = document.querySelector('#webcam');
    var button = document.querySelector('#screenshot-button');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#screenshot-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia
                    (
                      { video: true },
                      function (localMediaStream) {
                          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                      }, onFailure);
    }
    else {
        onFailure();
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);

    function snapshot() {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should save a reference to your stream, like this:

```
function (localMediaStream) {
    myStream = localMediaStream;
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myStream);
}, onFailure);
```

later on you can use:

```
myStream.stop(); 
myStream = null;
```